# Glassfish+ActiveMQ MDB processes message with 120 sec delay

Tags: java, glassfish, jms, activemq-classic

I`ve configured MDB for listening to the Queue on external ActiveMQ broker. It works fine, but MDB takes a message from the queue and starts processing only after 2 minutes delay. I haven't configured any timeouts, but it really looks like there is a kind of property that delays the processing. Could someone advise how can I tune this delay and switch to immediate processing?

Comment: I have encountered exact same problem. Takes 120 secs to complete sending to queue.

I only see this on Glassfish 4.1.1 (Centos 6) but Glassfish 4.1 (Windows 10) is fine.

Did you find a solution?

Comment: It could maybe be more helpful if you provided your activemq.xml.
I had a similar problem, but the environment was little different then yours (we used JBoss EAP 7 instad of Glassfish). The delays we experienced were however somewhat of variable duration. We solved it by specifying "pendingMessageLimitStrategy". Take a look at http://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumer-handling.html, maybe it will get you closer.

Comment: Showing your configuration, as well as the code calling activemq would probably help everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an  old bug in Glassfish for a long time.

There was a bug recorded here but now this site also closed .
http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-1429

Add System.exit(0) (in a finally block), which closes all threads.

```
try{
code ...

}finally{
 System.exit(0) ;
}
```

You can also enable debugging :

1) enable jstack to see how many threads from the mdb-thread-pool are in
use.

2) try enabling monitoring statistics of work-manager and thread-pools :
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19879-01/820-4335/6nfqc3qp8/index.html

Comment: I've tried to generate thread dump using the JVM report but can't figure out anything suspect but it really appears to have been a glassfish bug because on reverting to other glassfish version, 4.1 (other than 4.1.1), this problem is not there. I consider this answered. 

Thanks Khan